# Where are custom functions located

Tags: functions

When I in Ubuntu runs the `mario(){echo "Sorry, Mario is in another castle";}` in the console, where does this gets saved, and how do I remove the function `mario`?

Comment: @Rinzwind, `sudo nano /home/.bashrc` creates a new file. So it's not located there.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, but when I searches `/home/ubuntu/.bashrc` for `mario`, there comes no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions defined as you described it are only stored temporarily in the RAM. As soon as you end a bash session, they're gone.

You can, however place them in a textfile (let's say you call it `its-ah_me`), then you can load it into a new bash session with `. its-ah_me` (mind the gap after the dot).

Alternatively, you can write the function into the file `.bashrc` in your home directory (create it, if it doesn't exist). The `.bashrc` file is automatically loaded ("sourced") when a bash session is started.